# windows authentication c# hardcode credentials

Tags: c#, windows, authentication

Is there some way by which i can hardcode the username and password in my code for windows authentication in c# ?

I am making a connection like below :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=mydb.net;Initial Catalog=MyDatamart;Integrated Security=SSPI");
string selectSQL = "select * from myTable";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, conn);
```

The database which I am accessing has Windows authentication enabled.Is there someway I can hardcode my username and password to the code so that anyone (even someone who doesn't have access to the db ) can access the db when they run my code?

Comment: Move the connection string to configuration file.

Comment: Kurubaran- How will  that help ? Don't we move connection strings to web.config when we need to use it multiple times ? I am using this only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, but no, you shouldn't. The entire idea behind Windows authentication is to hide username and password so it is secure. It always uses the current logged-in Windows user as connecting user.

You can use some ways of impersonating the application user, providing it a username and password.

The best post I have used can be found here: [How do you do Impersonation in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net).